# No print output with functions

Tags: python, function

I've created multiple functions that doesn't output the final number as the print, can anyone help please. Thanks.

```
strips = int(input('Enter your number of strips: '))
lower = int(input('Enter your lower limit'))
upper = int(input('Enter your upper limit'))

#define Trapzeium rule
def trapezium(function3,lower,upper,strips):
    h=float(upper-lower)/strips
    result=0.5*function3(lower)+0.5*function3(upper)
    for i in range(1,strips):
        result+=function3(lower+i*h)
    result=h*result
    return result

#define function3
def function3(x):
    return 3*(x**2)*exp(x**3)
    trapezium_numerical=trapezium(function3,lower,upper,strips)
    print(trapezium_numerical)
```

Comment: Why assume that the limits of integration are ints? Using `float()` for those.

Comment: Take your `trapezium_numerical=...` and `print(...` out of `function3`.

Comment: The function only executes until the return. Return must be the last instruction

Comment: Thanks for the insight, How should I proceed with changing my code to achieve the right result?

Comment: I want to be able to keep everything within callable functions.

Comment: How should I proceed with changing my code to achieve the right result - please define the right result you expect?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I want to be able to achieve the output number using these two functions or condense it into one function

Comment: what is your expected output? it will help others to know the expected input and output.

Comment: I just want the calculated output so 2.659596.... when I input 1 as lower, 10 as upper, 10 as strips with the equation 3*(x^2)*exp^(x^3)